# How to get the list of all installed color schemes in Vim?

Tags: list, vim, color-scheme

Is there a way to get a list of all installed color schemes in Vim? That would make very easy to select one without looking at the `.vim` directory.

Answer (score 721, accepted):

Type

`:colorscheme` then <kbd>Space</kbd> followed by <kbd>TAB</kbd>.

or as Peter said,

`:colorscheme` then <kbd>Space</kbd> followed by <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>

The short version of the command is `:colo` so you can use it in the two previous commands, instead of using the "long form".

Comment: <c-d> is actually better if you have lots of scheme installed.

Comment: Or if you've got `:set wildmenu` you sorta get the same effect as `<c-d>` with hitting tab.

Comment: Worked for me after I added space after `:colorscheme`. Maybe it's something trivial, however, it took me time to reveal.

Comment: @jutky : you are right, otherwise it only complete the command name. I will update the answer accordingly.

Comment: it's also a bit faster to use `:colo` instead of `:colorscheme`

Comment: `:colo` isn't really the *short-form*. It's just completed because there are no conflicting commands. If you made a command like "colobanana", then `:colo` would have more than one "long form", so it wouldn't work as suggested.

Comment: Thus, all boils down to: There is no way to get a list if the default colour schemes in vim and the only way to be able to see which ones are there is by using tab expansion and painstakingly go through all of them and eventually create a list yourself. ;)

Comment: you can use :r! ls /usr/share/vim/vimNN/colors 
this will output a list of all colorschemes directly to the file opened in vim...from there you can set your colorscheme and delete the list after ( consider using something like ... 18dd command in vim to delete them all in one go... )

Comment: It would be nice if there was a gallery of all the built-in schemes.

Comment: The website vimcolors does not work anymore.

Answer (score 74):

Just for convenient reference. Here is a list of the default set of colour schemes for Vim 7.4:

```
blue.vim
darkblue.vim,
delek.vim
desert.vim
elflord.vim
evening.vim
industry.vim                                                                                                                                                 
koehler.vim                                                                                                                                                  
morning.vim                                                                                                                                                  
murphy.vim                                                                                                                                                   
pablo.vim                                                                                                                                                    
peachpuff.vim                                                                                                                                                
ron.vim                                                                                                                                                      
shine.vim                                                                                                                                                    
slate.vim                                                                                                                                                    
torte.vim                                                                                                                                                    
zellner.vim
```

Comment: Very helpful list.  For those with older eyes, and who are even busier, here are those I found most readable :  delek, koehler, slate & zellner.  I selected zellner.

Comment: Good choices, but maybe a bit too much of red color for me. I prefer desert, which uses turquoise/light blue.  (In vim, type :colors desert)

Comment: I've always used *torte* which to me seems to have good contrast and doesn't try to be a "style", and doesn't "waste contrast bandwidth" by making the colours similar.

Comment: To get this list for your version of vim, execute from within vim `:! ls $VIMRUNTIME/colors`

Answer (score 63):

You can see the list of color schemes under `/usr/share/vim/vimNN/colors` (with `NN` being the version, e.g. `vim74` for vim 7.4).

This is explained [here](https://www.linux.com/training-tutorials/weekend-project-take-control-vims-color-scheme/).

On the linux servers I use via ssh, <kbd>TAB</kbd> prints `^I` and <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> prints `^D`.

Comment: That misses the color schemes installed by the user (under the home directory).

Comment: The path to the color tables, exactly what I was looking for thanks!

Comment: Note that the `NN` in `vimNN` will correspond to the version of vim, e.g. `vim74` for vim 7.4. Just wanted to point this out because I'm slow and it made me do a double take when I went to look ;)

Comment: @AdamP I added the precision in the answer.

Comment: If you don't have the folder `/usr/share/vim/` you may have a minimal version of vim installed. In my case (a RHEL 8 vm) it came with `vim-minimal` only. I installed `vim-enhanced` which provided the color schemes.

Comment: The link is dead :(

Answer (score 17):

If you are willing to install a plugin, I recommend https://github.com/vim-scripts/CycleColor.

to cycle through all installed colorschemes. Nice way to easily choose a colorscheme.

Answer (score 10):

Looking at my system's menu.vim (look for 'Color Scheme submenu') and @chappar's answer, I came up with the following function:

```
" Returns the list of available color schemes
function! GetColorSchemes()
   return uniq(sort(map(
   \  globpath(&runtimepath, "colors/*.vim", 0, 1),  
   \  'fnamemodify(v:val, ":t:r")'
   \)))
endfunction
```

It does the following:

1. Gets the list of available color scheme scripts under all runtime
   paths (globpath, runtimepath)
2. Maps the script paths to their base names (strips parent dirs and
   extension) (map, fnamemodify)
3. Sorts and removes duplicates (uniq, sort)

Then to use the function I do something like this:

```
let s:schemes = GetColorSchemes()
if index(s:schemes, 'solarized') >= 0
   colorscheme solarized
elseif index(s:schemes, 'darkblue') >= 0
   colorscheme darkblue
endif
```

Which means I prefer the 'solarized' and then the 'darkblue' schemes; if none of them is available, do nothing.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a small function I wrote to try all the colorschemes in $VIMRUNTIME/colors directory.

Add the below function to your vimrc, then open your source file and call the function from command.

```
function! DisplayColorSchemes()
   let currDir = getcwd()
   exec "cd $VIMRUNTIME/colors"
   for myCol in split(glob("*"), '\n')
      if myCol =~ '\.vim'
         let mycol = substitute(myCol, '\.vim', '', '')
         exec "colorscheme " . mycol
         exec "redraw!"
         echo "colorscheme = ". myCol
         sleep 2
      endif
   endfor
   exec "cd " . currDir
endfunction
```

Comment: call DisplayColorSchemes()

Answer (score 8):

If you have your vim compiled with `+menu`, you can follow menus with the `:help` of `console-menu`. From there, you can navigate to `Edit.Color\ Scheme` to get the same list as with in `gvim`.

Other method is to use a cool script [ScrollColors](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1488) that previews the colorschemes while you scroll the schemes with `j/k`.

Answer (score 5):

i know i am late for this answer but the correct answer seems to be

See `:help getcompletion():`

```
:echo getcompletion('', 'color')
```

which you can assign to a variable:

```
:let foo = getcompletion('', 'color')
```

or use in an expression register:

```
:put=getcompletion('', 'color')
```

This is not my answer, this solution is provided by *u/romainl* in [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/hwgxq1/get_a_full_list_of_colorschemes_from_vim/) post on reddit.

Answer (score 3):

A great solution, and my thanks to your contributors. For years I've been struggling with a totally crappy color scheme -- using SSH under Windows Vista to a Redhat system, terminal type xterm.
The editor would come up with a black background and weird colors for various keywords. 
Worse -- that weird color scheme sticks in the xterm terminal after leaving Vim.

Really confusing.

Also, Backspace failed during an insert mode, which was nasty to remember -- though Delete did the same thing.

The cure --

1. In the SSH monitor, select Edit/Settings.

   a. Choose Profile Settings/Colors

   b. check 'enable ANSI colors'

   c. The standard Text colors are probably OK
2. Add these lines to $HOME/.vimrc:

   colorscheme default

   if &term == "xterm"

   set t_kb=^H

   fixdel

   endif
3. NOTE: the ^H MUST be typed as ctrl-V ctrl-H.  Seems peculiar, but this seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
set wildmenu
set wildmode=list:full
set wildcharm=<C-z>
let mapleader=','
nnoremap <leader>c :colorscheme <C-z><S-Tab>
```

in your `~/.vimrc`.

The first two lines make possible matches appear as lists. You can use either or both.

The fourth line makes leader `,` instead of the default `\`.

The last line allows you to simply type `,c` to get a list and a prompt to change your colorscheme.

The third line effectively allows for `Tab`s to appear in key maps.

(Of course, all of these strategies I've learned from the internet, and mostly SO, very recently.)

Comment: If I'm reading this right, `<C-z>` (and I may not be) will remap the default ctrl-z to background your editor, which is something I do *all* the time. So beware of binding this keymap if you don't know what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

Another simpler way is while you are editing a file - `tabe ~/.vim/colors/` **ENTER**
Will open all the themes in a new tab within vim window.

You may come back to the file you were editing using - `CTRL + W + W` **ENTER**

Note: Above will work ONLY IF YOU HAVE a `.vim/colors` directory within your home directory for current `$USER`
(I have 70+ themes)

> [user@host ~]$ ls -l ~/.vim/colors | wc -l
>
> 72